# Change rectangle Background when selecting a pressing a Button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles

Basically this is a button existing out of rectangle and several textblocks. The rectangle `Fill` is representing the background of my button. How can i change this when the button is pressed?

***The background also has to stay in that color after pressing the button.*** This basically shows the user visually what buttons have been pressed and what not.

**Part of my Style:**

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyleReg" TargetType="{x:Type myClasses:RegButton}">
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Grid x:Name="regButton">
                <Rectangle Name="rectangleBtn" Fill="#FF89959A" Height="Auto" RadiusY="15" RadiusX="15" Stroke="White" Width="Auto"/>                                             
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True"/>
                <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True"/>
                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True" >
                    <Setter TargetName="rectangleBtn" Property="Fill" Value="Blue" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10.667"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must address the correct element, try giving the rectangle a name and pointing the setter to it by name reference:

```
<Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid x:Name="regButton">
                    <Rectangle Fill="#FF89959A"
                               x:Name="rect"
                               Height="Auto"
                               RadiusY="15"
                               RadiusX="15"
                               Stroke="White"
                               Width="Auto" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused"
                             Value="True" />
                    <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted"
                             Value="True" />
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed"
                             Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background"
                                TargetName="rect"
                                Value="Blue" />
                        <!--??-->
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                             Value="False" />
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: I have tried this (edited my post) it does change but how do i keep that fill color? Seems i am not in need of the "isPressed" trigger.

Comment: For this, you must use a `ToggleButton` and Set a trigger on the `IsChecked` Property. `ToggleButton` remembers its state. Generally speaking, a Trigger looks up the Value of a dependency property when it changes. `Button.IsPressed` changes once when you press the button and a second time when you release it. `ToggleButton.IsChecked` is a state that's set and kept.

Comment: Could you illustrate that? Never heard of it before cheers. My button is already a repeatButton by nature (for my program functionality). So i assume i cannot just change my button like that?

Comment: I have updated my comment to explain Triggers and the `IsChecked` Property.In your case, the simplest thing coming to my mind is creating your own class derived from `RepeatButton` and adding an `IsPressed` Dependency Property. After that you have to take care of setting the DPs value - do you want to toggle on mouse up (once per mouse down) or every time the repeat fires? The latter would turn the button into a disco button, surely =)